# C++ HowTo: Non-template class inheriting from an abstract specialized template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a non-template abstract base class which is used in order to be able to have a reference to the base type, since unspecialized template types can't be used as method arguments.

```cpp
#ifndef RPCPP_ICALLBACKBASE_H
#define RPCPP_ICALLBACKBASE_H

#include <string>

namespace rpcpp
{
    class ICallbackBase
{
public:
    virtual ~ICallbackBase() {};
    virtual void OnSuccess(void result) = 0;
    virtual void OnError(std::string error) = 0;
};
}

#endif // RPCPP_ICALLBACKBASE_H
```

The abstract template class ICallback inherits from ICallback base, like so:

```cpp
#ifndef RPCPP_ICALLBACK_H
#define RPCPP_ICALLBACK_H

#include "ICallbackBase.h"

namespace rpcpp
{
template <class T>
class ICallback : public ICallbackBase
{
public:
    virtual ~ICallback() {};
    virtual void OnSuccess(T result) = 0;
    virtual void OnError(std::string error) = 0;
};
}

#endif // RPCPP_ICALLBACK_H
```

Finally, one can create a concrete type by inheriting from ICallback:

```cpp
#ifndef RPCPP_SAMPLE_CALLBACK_H
#define RPCPP_SAMPLE_CALLBACK_H

#include "ICallback.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace rpcpp
{
class SampleCallback : public ICallback<double>
{
public:
    ~SampleCallback() {};

    virtual void OnSuccess(double result)
    {
        std::cout << "Successfully executed a remote procedure, A + B = " << result << "\r\n\r\n";
    }

    virtual void OnError(std::string error)
    {
        std::cout << "Error while executing a remote procedure: " << error << "\r\n\r\n";
    }
};
}

#endif // RPCPP_SAMPLE_CALLBACK_H
```

All of which compiles nice, however when i try to use this, like so:

```cpp
rpcpp::SampleCallback sc;
sic.CalculateMean(15, 28, &sc); // Third argument of this method is expected to be ICallbackBase&.
```

It produces the following two errors:

"cannot instantiate abstract class" in line #1.
"cannot convert parameter 3 from SampleCallback& to ICallbackBase&" in line #2

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You said it takes a reference, but you are passing a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
virtual void OnSuccess(void result) = 0;
```

is never defined.

Comment: Which would mean that my template inheritance from a Non-template base class is wrong, what is the proper way of making a template inherit an abstract method from a non-template base?

Comment: This is not related to templates. A class with pure virtual functions is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated. You can instantiate a derived class only if it defines all pure virtual functions in the base class.

Comment: But the whole point of why I did this in the first place, is to have virtual void OnSuccess(T result) = 0; inherit (override) virtual void OnSuccess(void) = 0; from the base class.

Comment: That is not possible. You need to override OnSuccess in the derived class with the exact same (non-templated) signature. It can then call a templated function that belongs only to the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

you are not implementing every abstract method:

> virtual void OnSuccess(void result) = 0;

and what is the definition of CalculateMean?

Comment: I thought that I could somehow have a non-template base class which declares a common interface, and a template derived class which 'templatizes' the interface, so that I can use a pointer to the base class to hold template instances and call their methods like this: ICallbackBase* foo; foo->OnSuccess(3.54);

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to fix the actual problem:

Remove the parameter from OnSuccess:

```
virtual void OnSuccess()=0;
```

Add a constructor parameter to ICallback:

```
template<class T> class ICallBack
{
public:
   ICallBack(T &result) : result(result) { }
protected:
   T &result;
};
```

Add new methods to allow non-template code to access T internal representation:

```
virtual void *Address() const=0;
virtual size_t Size() const=0;
virtual type_info Type() const=0;
```

Implement those methods in `ICallBack<T>`:

```
void *Address() const { return &result; }
size_t Size() const { return sizeof(T); }
type_info Type() const { return typeid(T); }
```